# Could not connect to virtual machine Docker

Tags: docker, virtual-machine, hyper-v

[image: this image shows that i connect to docker virtual machine.]

I am using Docker for windows and on hyper-v. I have created this virtual machine but I cant connect to it, and get an error message saying:

> "Could not Connect to the virtual machine Try to connect again. if the
>   problem persists , contact your system administrator".

I have browsed docker documentation but cant get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal. You can't get a video-out connection to the VM, because that's not how it is used. Instead, you should be starting a PowerShell prompt and running docker commands from there.

Comment: I run command docker info on powershell and get the error . I have not added ennvironment variable for docker do I have to add it

Comment: you should not need to do anything but install Docker for Windows, run it so that Docker Moby icon shows up in bottom right system tray, and start PowerShell to run `docker info`.

Comment: Bret Fisher I have taken your course on udemy. And also on slack. But docker info also gives error.

Comment: Yea the course Q&A or Slack is likely an easier place to troubleshoot your windows machine than this. You've got something wrong with your computer, as Docker will "just work" after install, assuming AV, 3rd party firewalls, or other security software isn't preventing it from running.